# "is no longer working" vs "does not work anymore"

Tags: grammar, differences, sentence

> Mr.John does not work in plaza hotel, anymore

vs

> Mr.John is no longer working at plaza hotel

Which one is correct to say? If he's not working, currently.

Comment: Are you asking about the tense or anymore vs. no longer? These are orthogonal questions.

Answer (score 3):

Either can be used with slight modification. At least in American English, it's common to preface a hotel name with "the" (e.g. "We're staying at the Hilton").

You could then choose from:

> Mr. John does not work at the Plaza Hotel anymore.
>
> Mr. John is no longer working at the Plaza Hotel.

Answer (score 2):

**Both are correct** but if John is a first name I wouldn't say Mr.John.

In addition to

> - "John doesn't work at the Plaza anymore."
> - "John is no longer working at the Plaza".

You could also say:

> - John isn't working at the Plaza any longer.
> - No longer is John working at the Plaza.